# how to implement online exam project source code in jsp servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

thanks in advance,
guys I need to develop source code for online exam for an academic projects and I have equipped with  net beans ,MySQL db,so please someone give me ideas about how to start this project.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/online-skills-assessment/9379895). This might help you create one of your own.